# How to bootstrap an Express / Angular app with a user object?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

During the initial request, how can I load a user object (or any object) on an Express back-end and then populate an Angular app as soon as it is loaded?  I have an application that I am sending a JWT token to.  I have sucessfully validated the session and loaded the initial data (user object, etc.) that the application needs.  I just cannot figure out how to load it with the Angular app.

Comment: What do you mean by "populate an Angular app"? Do you mean the Express server will render a page with an initial payload for angular?

Comment: @guzart: I'm assuming so, yes.  I remember seeing something like this is an Angular tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Embed it in the page at the server side, perhaps using a templating engine.

See mean.js framework, it does <strike>something similar</strike> exactly that.
https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/app/views/layout.server.view.html

Comment: Sure, I'm using Jade / Express so I can add anything to the page.  My problem is that I have no idea how to get it out of the page and use it with Angular.

Comment: @G.Deward If you embed it in the page, you can parse it out of the dom with angular in an angular controller/service/whatever: `angular.element('#my-server-data-element').html()` or `.attr('some-field')`. It's dirty, and I wouldn't do this if you wanted to hide whatever it is from the user as they could easily find it in the page source.

Comment: @G.Deward you can just follow the approach meanjs took and declare it as a variable at the window scope. 
Then inject it via a service. So if you embedded it in your page like `var user = {json}` you can inject $window to an `Authentication` service, and from there return `$window.user` as a property. 
https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/public/modules/users/services/authentication.client.service.js

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing would be to embed the JSON object as a global in the rendered page. If you are using Jade, it would look something like this

```
- hello = {"hello": 234}
script(type="text/javascript")
  != 'window.hello =' + JSON.stringify(hello) + ';'
```

So now the object is globally available at `window.hello`, and you can access it from your angular code inside a `<script src="..."></script>`

*Note*: I strongly recommend against this, it could lead to spaghetti code. And even if it sounds delicious it's hard maintain. Instead I would suggest you completely decouple your angular app from the server side rendering. But if you are only using this technique for User information, I guess it's not too bad®.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

in your template (generated server side) you can add something similar to this

```
<script>
angular.module('myConfig', [])
  .value('jwt', {...});
</script>
```

then you can inject myConfig as a dependency of you angular app and you have access to jwt value within the app

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myConfig'])
  .factory('myFactory', function($http, jwt){
    return {};
    });
```